# Python - Converting a string with escape characters to json

Tags: python, json, regex, string

JSON objects are printed into my syslog file. I need to extract the string from the log and convert it into JSON. I don't have any problems extracting the string between '`{`' and '`}`', but certain strings have an escape character in them, and this is causing `json.loads` to fail

Here is the problem:

```
>>> import json
>>> resp = '{"from_hostname": {"value": "mysite.edu\"", "value2": 0, "value3": 1}}'
>>> json.loads(resp)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 41 (char 40)
>>> resp[40]
'"'
>>> resp[41]
','
>>> resp[39]
'"'
>>>
```

When `json` sees the `\"` I guess it only sees `"` and assumes that the string is over, and it throws the delimiter error.

I tried replacing `\"` with `\\"` but that doesn't seem to work.

NOTE: The `\"` can occur at the beginning or end or in the middle of the string.

How do I get this working?

Comment: If you print `resp`, there will be no ``\``: `{"from_hostname": {"value": "mysite.edu"", "value2": 0, "value3": 1}}`

Comment: Do the always appear in the values? You can try `resp = re.sub(r'(:\s*")([^,]*)",', lambda x: x.group(1) + x.group(2).replace("\"", r"\"") + '",', resp)`, and then `print(json.loads(resp))`

Comment: How are you extracting the JSON strings? Can you post that code too?

Answer (score 7):

if `\"` can occur in your string you have to escape `\` and `"` with

```
import json
resp = '{"from_hostname": {"value": "mysite.edu\\\"", "value2": 0, "value3": 1}}'
print(json.loads(resp))
```

it prints

```
{u'from_hostname': {u'value3': 1, u'value2': 0, u'value': u'mysite.edu"'}}
```

is this the right interpration of your question?

Comment: hi, yes, however I had problem appending extra escape characters to the string. What ever the number of escape characters I add, I still didn't see the \ appended in the string.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the backslash character is escaping the double quote in the Python string, but it is not actually present in the string. Printing the string demonstrates this:

```
>>> print '{"from_hostname": {"value": "mysite.edu\"", "value2": 0, "value3": 1}}'
'{"from_hostname": {"value": "mysite.edu"", "value2": 0, "value3": 1}}'
```

This shows that the backslash is *not* in the string. So the double quote must be escaped for the string to be a valid JSON string, which means that the backslash must be present in the string. You can do that by escaping the backslash itself with another backslash, i.e. `\\`:

```
>>> print '{"from_hostname": {"value": "mysite.edu\\"", "value2": 0, "value3": 1}}'
{"from_hostname": {"value": "mysite.edu\"", "value2": 0, "value3": 1}}
```

and `json.loads()` now works:

```
>>> json.loads('{"from_hostname": {"value": "mysite.edu\\"", "value2": 0, "value3": 1}}')
{u'from_hostname': {u'value3': 1, u'value2': 0, u'value': u'mysite.edu"'}}
```

Or you could use a raw string:

```
>>> json.loads(r'{"from_hostname": {"value": "mysite.edu\"", "value2": 0, "value3": 1}}')
{u'from_hostname': {u'value3': 1, u'value2': 0, u'value': u'mysite.edu"'}}
```

---

However, `json.loads()` fails on JSON strings that you extracted from the log file which strongly suggests that the problem is there. You should post the extraction code in your question so that can be checked.

Comment: yes, this was exactly what I started doing, and I was stuck at adding the extra \ to the string. I tried str.replace('\"', '\\"'), and some other variants but couldn't add the additional \.. Can you please help, i know this is basics but for some reason couldn't get past this.

Comment: Can you post the code that extracts the JSON strings from the log file and a sample of the file? If the file contains valid JSON, you shouldn't need to perform any substitutions.